# CXF interceptors not working

Tags: java, web-services, cxf

I've created web service cxf client that simply sends soap message to given endpoint, and I have got some, I think, strange issue. 
First of all, I don't know why I get a lot of debug logs, and second, more important issue is that interceptors aren't working. Nor mine or those from CXF framework. 
I have created classes using wsimport from wsdl, so I suppose this issues are not related to them (I have done a lot of client-service applications and didn't have any problem with this tool).
Here's my main class:

```
    System.setProperty("com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServerProvider",
               "org.mortbay.jetty.j2se6.JettyHttpServerProvider");
    JaxWsProxyFactoryBean factory = new JaxWsProxyFactoryBean();
    factory.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
    factory.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());
    factory.setAddress(ADDRESS);
    factory.setServiceClass(WebserviceInterface.class);
    factory.setUsername("usr");
    factory.setPassword("pass");
    Main main = new Main();
    main.operation = (WebserviceInterface) factory.create();

    WebServiceRequest request = main.generateRequest();

    main.operation.someWebServiceOperation(request);
```

Here I add default cxf interceptors but it didn't work so I've created my own interceptors:
IN:

```
public class LoggingInInterceptor extends AbstractSoapInterceptor {

private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(LoggingInInterceptor.class.getName());

public LoggingInInterceptor () {
    super(Phase.RECEIVE);
}

@Override
public void handleMessage(SoapMessage message) throws Fault {
    LOG.log(Level.INFO, "\n\n\n\nhandleMessage called\n\n\n\n");
    InputStream is = message.getContent(InputStream.class);
    CachedOutputStream os = new CachedOutputStream();
    try {
        IOUtils.copy(is, os);
        os.flush();
        message.setContent(InputStream.class, os.getInputStream());
        is.close();
        GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
        Date date = new Date();
        calendar.setTime(date); //gets current date and time
        XMLGregorianCalendar timestamp = DatatypeFactory
                                            .newInstance()
                                            .newXMLGregorianCalendar(calendar);
        System.out.println("Received at " + timestamp + ":\n" + XMLFormatter.format(IOUtils.toString(os.getInputStream())));//NOPMD
        System.out.println("----------------------------" + "\n\n");//NOPMD
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOG.log(Level.WARNING, e.getMessage(), IOException.class);
    } catch (DocumentException e) {
        LOG.log(Level.WARNING, e.getMessage(), DocumentException.class);
    } catch (DatatypeConfigurationException e) {
        LOG.log(Level.WARNING, e.getMessage(), DatatypeConfigurationException.class);
    }
}
```

}

OUT:

```
public class LogginOutInterceptor extends LoggingOutInterceptor {

private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(LogginOutInterceptor.class.getName());

public LogginOutInterceptor() {
    super(Phase.PRE_STREAM);
}

@Override
public void handleMessage(Message message) {
    OutputStream out = message.getContent(OutputStream.class);
    final CacheAndWriteOutputStream newOut = new CacheAndWriteOutputStream(out);
    message.setContent(OutputStream.class, newOut);
    newOut.registerCallback(new LoggingCallback());
}

public class LoggingCallback implements CachedOutputStreamCallback {

    @Override
    public void onFlush(CachedOutputStream cos) {
    }

    /**
     * Prints outgoing message on the screen. 
     */
    @Override
    public void onClose(CachedOutputStream cos) {
        try {
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            cos.writeCacheTo(builder, limit);
            String soapXml = builder.toString();
            GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
            Date date = new Date();
            calendar.setTime(date); //gets current date and time
            XMLGregorianCalendar timestamp = DatatypeFactory
                                                .newInstance()
                                                .newXMLGregorianCalendar(calendar);
            System.out.println("Sent at " + timestamp + ":\n" + XMLFormatter.format(soapXml));//NOPMD
            System.out.println("----------------------------" + "\n\n");//NOPMD
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.log(Level.WARNING, e.getMessage(), Exception.class);
        }
    }
}
```

}

I get `Skipping interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor: Phase receive specified does not exist.` But I don't know why.

And my second question is why I get so many logs on console? I get something like this:

```
08:37:33.829 [main] DEBUG org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl - Interceptors contributed by databinding: []
08:37:33.832 [main] DEBUG o.a.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyOutInterceptor@194164c to phase setup
08:37:33.833 [main] WARN  o.a.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Skipping interceptor com.steria.sm.LoggingInInterceptor: Phase receive specified does not exist.
08:37:33.833 [main] DEBUG o.a.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor@1fc9a67 to phase prepare-send
08:37:33.834 [main] DEBUG o.a.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.SwAOutInterceptor@fcf5ba to phase pre-logical
08:37:33.835 [main] DEBUG o.a.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.WrapperClassOutInterceptor@16889eb to phase pre-logical
08:37:33.836 [main] DEBUG o.a.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.jaxws.interceptors.HolderOutInterceptor@36c8f3 to phase pre-logical
08:37:33.837 [main] DEBUG o.a.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.AttachmentOutInterceptor@c3020c to phase pre-stream
08:37:33.838 [main] DEBUG o.a.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.interceptor.StaxOutInterceptor@bb8a39 to phase pre-stream
08:37:33.839 [main] DEBUG o.a.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapHeaderOutFilterInterceptor@6fd7d9 to phase pre-logical
08:37:33.840 [main] DEBUG o.a.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.wsdl.interceptors.BareOutInterceptor@c412dd to phase marshal
08:37:33.841 [main] DEBUG o.a.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapPreProtocolOutInterceptor@b2aa22 to phase post-logical
08:37:33.842 [main] DEBUG o.a.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain - Adding interceptor org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor@1bfcec0 to phase write
```

I don't want to post all of those logs because it's a lot of them.

Is anyone knows what did I wrong? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you have interchanged the interceptors:

```
factory.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
factory.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());
```